# www url rewrite not working (Read All Other Threads)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite

```
example.com to www.example.com
```

My Code in apache2.conf (Main config file of apache in Linux/ubuntu 32bit ):

try 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Restart Apache Code Doesn't Work !

try 2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Restart Apache Code Doesn't Work !

try 3:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Restart Apache Code Doesn't Work !

Loaded Modules in apache displays:

```
rewrite_module (shared)
```

How can i solve this ?

And is there any other mod i have to enable(I don't think so).

I have to put this code in some other file ?

It is neccessary/must use .htaccess for url rewriting ?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are fine.

1. Make sure the rules are in the *virtualhost* of the "example.com" domain. If you have no "example.com" vhost, then place the rules in the *first vhost container*. S

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       ....

       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

       ....
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Try putting the rules in a directory container:

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www/path/of/your/document_root/">
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   </Directory>
   ```

Comment: first thank you very much, second why virtualhost directory code works but not main config file code ?